# script works on jsfiddle but not in site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having the following validation script in jquery:
http://jsfiddle.net/0ybrx00q/

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
if ($.isNumeric($("input[name=commodity]").val()) === false) {
    $(".error_show").text("kosten müssen Zahl sein!").show();
    event.preventDefault();

} else if ($("input[name=plz]").val().length != 5) {
    $(".error_show").text("PLZ muss aus 5 Zeichen bestehen!").show();
    event.preventDefault();
} else if ($.isNumeric($("input[name=leistung]").val()) === false) {
    $(".error_show").text("Leistung muss Zahl sein!").show();
    event.preventDefault();
} else if ($("input[name=nb]").val() === "") {
    $(".error_show").text("Kein angebot!").show();
    event.preventDefault();
} else {
    $(".error_show").text("Validated...").show();
    return;
}
});
```

In the external file I have saved the script in,there is another function that does work.However,I cannot use the above script to validate my form because even if I leave everything empty,you can press the submit button.The event.preventDefault() does not work there and there is also no "Validated..." message(so the script is just ignored).

Is there anything I'm missing?I can't seem to find any problem there since it is exactly the same code .

Comment: What error you are getting?
Have you taken the reference of jquery file?

Comment: Have you verified if this script is loading before any other dependent script?

Comment: is your code inside ready handler?

Comment: It is loaded in head via <script> and has a $(document).ready(...) handler.

Comment: Look in your browser's developer tools. What does the JavaScript error console say?

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery before you load your script?

Comment: There is no error.I've set a breakpoint at the very first line in chrome,but after pausing the script,there is nothing else to observe.no error or warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it in a document.ready handler - jsfiddle does this for you automatically...

```
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        if ($.isNumeric($("input[name=commodity]").val()) === false) {
            $(".error_show").text("kosten müssen Zahl sein!").show();
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if ($("input[name=plz]").val().length != 5) {
            $(".error_show").text("PLZ muss aus 5 Zeichen bestehen!").show();
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if ($.isNumeric($("input[name=leistung]").val()) === false) {
            $(".error_show").text("Leistung muss Zahl sein!").show();
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if ($("input[name=nb]").val() === "") {
            $(".error_show").text("Kein angebot!").show();
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            $(".error_show").text("Validated...").show();
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The OP has indicated, in the comments on the question, that they have already done this.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin - he posted that after I'd posted this.  I'll leave it here for now and delete it if not helpful.

Comment: Actually,now it works.For some reason, $(function)(){...} works,but $(document).ready(function(){...} does not.Is there a difference between both ready handlers?

Comment: No - the one I use is just a shorthand version of `document.ready()`.  Well something must have been different, but at least it works now.  Glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: This sort of stuff can really drive you crazy.Thanky you :)